# Debug error 1046 only after the swf is loaded into another file?

Tags: actionscript

I am getting [error 1046](http://curtismorley.com/2007/06/20/flash-cs3-flex-2-as3-error-1046/) on a .swf file only AFTER I load it into another SWF file.

When I publish the swf on it's own, I get no error message.

After I load the swf into another swf, I get the 1046 error message.

I've tried changing the linkage name a few times but not luck.

I also combed through the swf I am loading into to see if there is a similar name to the linkage, but I don't see anything?

Comment: Are the publish setting in both SWFs the same?

Comment: Also, is the loading swf pushing it into another ApplicationDomain?  Also, you could be having issues with SecurityDomain as well -- are they on the same domain?